# Нужна ли запятая перед "способных" в данном предложении?

Tags: пунктуация

Нужна ли запятая в данном предложении? *Есть всего шесть человек способных работать с новейшими технологическими разработками.*

Comment: Запятая перед "способных" нужна. Впрочем, есть и такой вариант трактовки предложения: *"Есть всего шесть человек способных, [чтобы] работать с новейшими технологическими разработками"*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Рас­про­стра­нён­ные опре­де­ле­ния, выра­жен­ные при­ла­га­тель­ны­ми с зави­си­мы­ми сло­ва­ми, сто­я­щие после опре­де­ля­е­мо­го слова, выделяются запя­ты­ми.

> Мало най­дет­ся в нашей лите­ра­ту­ре таких щемя­щих рас­ска­зов, пол­ных скры­той люб­ви к просто­му чело­ве­ку.
>
> По реке нес­ло жел­то­ва­тую пену, похо­жую на сби­тый белок (К. Паустовский).